# Function asymptotic relation: why $g = O(f)$ implies $(f + g) \asymp f$?

Tags: functions, asymptotics

It is well-known that $f \asymp g$ at $a \in \mathbb{R}$ if there is a reduced neighborhood $U$ of $a$ and strictly positive constants $A_1$ and $A_2$ so that for all $x \in U$, we have $A_1 g (x) \le \vert f(x) \vert \le A_2 g (x)$.

It is listed as a fact at [link](https://math.fel.cvut.cz/mt/txtb/5/txe3ba5f.htm) that, if $g = O(f)$ at $a$, then $(f + g) \asymp f$ at $a$. The upper bound is easy to show. What about the lower bound? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It probably assumes $f,g\geq 0.$ Then $f+g\geq 1\cdot f.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s certainly not true for all $f,g.$ For example, when $f\geq 0$ and $g=-f,$ then $g=O(f)$ but $f+g=0,$ so it is wrong, in general, to say $f+g\asymp f.$

The author probably meant to restrict to $f,g\geq 0.$ Then $g+f\geq 1\cdot f.$

In a lot of common usages of this notation, although certainly not all, we are talking about non-negative functions.

Comment: I kind of hate the notation $f\asymp g$ because it loosely implies an equivalence, which is only true if $f,g\geq 0.$